# CouchDB Entity Relationships

Tags: couchdb

I'm coming from a SQL background and I've just started looking at CouchDB.

I'm trying to understand how CouchDB handles multiple relationships.

In SQL I would have a **product** table for example with rows containing columns which describe a product. For example `"ID", "Product Name", "Description", "Amount in Stock"`. I would then create a new **order** table and link this to the above mentioned **product** table by ID.

I understand that I can create a CouchDB order document and list the products with their data under this document. The problem I see is that if I have many of these orders and I want to edit the description, I would then need to edit all the order documents to reflect these changes.

My question is how would I go about designing this so that I only have to change the data in one document and it would be reflected in order documents containing this product?

Comment: You would store your data in multiple documents. Then using views and/or `include_docs` with your query to include related docs/data. There is not a way to update multiple docs in a single transaction, so building an ordering system may not be a good use for couchdb.

Comment: Not necessarilly, you can update multiple documents via the [_bulk_docs API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API). There is a querystring arg (`all_or_nothing=true`) that, with some caveats, does an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store description as field in order document, store only id of your product and every time you need your order with description you should get product from the database to check current value of description.

If you need to display lots of orders with different products in one table, you can query all products from the database at one query using "keys" parameter. It works pretty fast.

Comment: Works fast if it's little data or has already been indexed. Indexing can take awhile depending on box resources, data size and view complexity. 

As an added bonus: If you happen to change the view often and the re-index is killing you due to blocking nature, try creating a backup design view with the proper changes. It will index for both without blocking the previous view. Once done, save changes from the backup to the new design view -- no time waiting for the index and no down time for using the view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the method you describe, would I then have a document called Product with the fields "ID", "Description", and "Price" for example. Then I would have an Order document with fields "ID", "OrderedBy", "ProductID", "Amount"? If I then wanted to see the description of the product in a particular order, I would then reference the product using the ProductID?